# How to get country, Link, text from all anchors tags in array using php

Tags: php, arrays

How to get country, Link, text from all anchor tags in array using **PHP**

```
$str ='
<div class="main"> 
<span country="PK"></span><a class="link" href="linkOne">1</a> 
<span country="US"></span><a class="link" href="linkTwo">2</a> 
<span country="UA"></span><a class="link" href="LinkThree">3</a> 
</div>';
function getStr($str,$start,$end){
    $str = explode($start,$str,2);
    $str = explode($end,$str[1],2);
    return $str[0];
}
$html =  getStr($str,'<div class="main">','</div>');
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $html, $result);

if (!empty($result)) {
   echo $result['href'][0];
}
```

Need like this:

```
/* Array */
$links[0] = "PK", "linkOne", "1";
$links[1] = "US", "linkTwo", "2";
/* and so on ... */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for server-side `JQuery`, which in fact exists!

checkout [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/)

#### Usage example

In your specific case it could be used like:

```php
<?php
include 'phpQuery.php';

$str = '<span country="US"></span><a href="url-here">some text</a>';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($str);

// Note that we can use CSS style selector,
// instead of just "span".
$links = array();
foreach($doc['span'] as $item)
{
  $node = pq($item);
  $sibling = $node->next();
  if ( $sibling->is('a') ) {
    $links[] = array(
      $node->attr('country'),
      $sibling->attr('href'),
      $sibling->text(),
    );
  }
}

// Display result:
print_r($links);
```

Simply get [phpQuery-0.9.5.386-onefile.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/phpquery/phpQuery-0.9.5.386-onefile.zip), extract it and rename it to `phpQuery.php`, its a single file!!

Comment: Added more details and example, enjoy ;-)